# Why do the swap step in Prim's algorithm for minimum spanning trees?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis, greedy-algorithms, spanning-trees

I was watching the [video lecture from MIT on Prim's algorithm for minimum spanning trees](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-16-greedy-algorithms-minimum-spanning-trees/).
Why do we need to do the swap step for proving the theorem that if we choose a set of vertices  in minimum spanning tree of $G(V,E)$and let us call that $A$ such  $A\subset B$,  the edge with the least weight connecting $A$ to $V-A$ will always be in the minimum spanning tree ?  The professor has done the swap step at point 59:07 seconds in the video.

Comment: What kind of "why" are you looking for? (There are many proofs...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Charles Leiserson is presenting a proof to what is known as the **blue rule** in Tarjan's "Data Structures and Network Analysis" book.

The proof goes by contradiction, that is you assume that the edge $(u,v)$ is not in the MST $T$. Don't be confused by the board, it has to be $(u,v)\not \in T$. Let $(a,b)$ the edge that we swap with $(u,v)$. Bot edges are cut edges between $A$ and $A\setminus V$.
The tree $T'$ after the swap has weight 
$$w(T')=w(T)+w((u,v))-w((a,b)).$$ 
As a consequence $w(T')<w(T)$, which is a contradiction and therefor the assumption $(u,v)\not\in T$ was wrong.

Notice that this proof uses the assumption that all edge weights are distinct, however it is easy to modify it for general edge weights.